# Android 5.0 windowEnterTransition not affecting transition

Tags: android, android-transitions

I want my launcher activity to slide in from the right to the left when it is opened or returned to from a previous activity. It currently slides from the right to the left when it switches to another activity, but not when it is opened or the back button is pressed.

Here is the relevant XML for the style that is applied to my launcher activity:

styles.xml

```
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@android:transition/slide_left</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@android:transition/slide_left</item>
    <item name="android:windowReenterTransition">@android:transition/slide_right</item>
    <item name="android:windowReturnTransition">@android:transition/slide_left</item>
```

My activity moves to the next activity when a button is clicked.  This is my onClickListener:

```
Button register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registerBtn);
        register.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(LoginActivity.this).toBundle());
            }
        });
```

I believe the ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation method may have something to do with why the exit transition works, but how do I apply this for an enter transition?

Comment: did you figure out the problem? Im also having an issue setting an animation for the FAB when the main activity is launched

Comment: @Andrea No, sorry. I had abandoned this project of mine about a year ago, so I haven't had the opportunity to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If your activity is **AppCompatActivity**, try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(LoginActivity.this).toBundle();
ActivityCompat.startActivity(RegisterActivity.this, intent, bundle);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this to start a new activity with transition

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, NewActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

Create file res/anim/slide_in_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false" >
     <translate android:duration="1000" android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%" />
     <alpha android:duration="1000" android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

Create file res/anim/slide_out_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shareInterpolator="false" >
      <translate android:duration="2000" android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"/>
      <alpha android:duration="2000" android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

You can make your activity slide accordingly as per requirements using this method.